# .htaccess -> Nginx Config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Need snippet for nginx config file. Original .htaccess:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't support .htacess file. You can import your .htacess settings to nginx conf file.

You can use .htacess to nginx converter https://winginx.com/en/htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

if wordpress site is inside /var/www/html/web/wordpress then nginx config should be

```
location ~ ^/web/wordpress/index\.php$ { }

location /web/wordpress/ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/web/wordpress/(.*)$ /web/wordpress/index.php break;
}
}
```